# What is the correct way to filter a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I have an android app with a fairly large database of search suggestions, that I am trying to use in a SearchView. When a user enters text into the search view, I want to filter my search suggestions using their query.

Here was my original setup

```
protected void initToolbar(View rootView, String title) {
    searchView = (SearchView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.res_search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
    Cursor newCursor = SearchUtil.getSearchSuggestionsCursor(title);
    SearchCursorAdapter adapter = new SearchCursorAdapter(rootView.getContext(),newCursor);
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(adapter);
}   

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    if (query == null || query.length() < 2){
        return false;
    }

    SearchCursorAdapter adapter = (SearchCursorAdapter) searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
    if (adapter != null){
        Cursor newCursor = SearchUtil.getSearchSuggestionsCursor(query);
        adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using this logic, The app would crash sometimes with "Attempted to reopen closed object" and in general the UI felt a little sluggish at times if the user was typing rapidly.

Here is my new setup:

```
 protected void initToolbar(View rootView, String title) {
     searchView = (SearchView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.res_search_view);
     searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
     searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(this);
     Cursor newCursor = SearchUtil.getSearchSuggestionsCursor(title);
     SearchCursorAdapter adapter = new SearchCursorAdapter(rootView.getContext(),newCursor);

     adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
         @Override
         public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence charSequence) {
             if (charSequence != null){
                 return SearchUtil.getSearchSuggestionsCursor(charSequence.toString());
             } else {
                 return SearchUtil.getSearchSuggestionsCursor("");
             }
        }
    });
 }



 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
     searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getFilter().filter(query);
     return false;
 }
```

Using the FilterQueryProvider, all my problems seem to go away. My question is should I always be using the FilterQueryProvider.

Also, I am confused about how the cursor I return in the FilterQueryProvider is related to the cursor that I originally supply to the CursorAdapter.

Any explanation would be great

Comment: yes, `FilterQueryProvider` is the way you should use, or if you are extending some `CursorAdapter` you can override `runQueryOnBackgroundThread`, see [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#429)